# OSX equivalent bluetoothctl command

Tags: linux, macos, bluetooth, osx-elcapitan

When I use linux, i have a CLI ther eis `bluetoothctl` which I could use. Is there an equivalent one for MacOS? I am using OSX El Capitan.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming as required for Stackoverflow questions. Please review the [help/on-topic]. The question may be appropriate on other sites such as [Superuser](http://superuser.com) but do check their help before posting or requesting migration there.

Comment: Does it not fulfil this?
"software tools commonly used by programmers;"

I encountered this problem while programming and needed to investigate Bluetooth controls. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: You may be using the tool for programming but that doesn't make it a common programming tool. As you said, `bluetoothctl` is used for controlling bluetooth. And controlling bluetooth is not intrinsically related to programming (e.g. you may want to use it to connect to a bluetooth speaker to listen to music).

Comment: Sure. Your reasoning is fallacious but if my query is absurd please feel free to vote to close the question.

Comment: @NickyLim Did you find a solution to this?  I am wondering if there is an **hcitool** equivalent command on Mac OS.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Sorry, i have not found a solution to it. I just ended up using linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: 
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47503/how-to-control-bluetooth-wireless-radio-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth daemon is called blued. Killing it should restart it :

```
sudo pkill blued
```

You could also try :

```
sudo launchctl start/stop com.apple.blued
```

[source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251842/how-to-restart-bluetooth-service-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Install blueutil using Homebrew

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then

```
brew install blueutil
```